# How to return array of objects by checking its property and arraylist in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, arrayobject

how to compare array of objects with arrays using javascript

I need to check array of objects based on conditons

1. if the `targetvalue` is same and `code` does not have value in `arraylist` return array of objects
2. else if the `targetvalue` is same and `code` same value in `arraylist` return array of objects

else return []

```
var arraylist =["IT","FI"];
var arrobj1 =[
  {id:1, name: "sonu", code: "IT", targetvalue: "908"},
  {id:2, name: "abi", code: "IT", targetvalue: "834"},
  {id:3, name: "lisa", code: "SP", targetvalue: "834"},
  {id:4, name: "ben", code: "FI", targetvalue: "234"},
]

Expected Output 
//same value , and has "IT" 
[]

****

var arrobj2 =[
  {id:1, name: "sonu", code: "IT", targetvalue: "908"},
  {id:2, name: "abi", code: "IT", targetvalue: "834"},
  {id:3, name: "lisa", code: "SG", targetvalue: "234"},
  {id:4, name: "ben", code: "SP", targetvalue: "234"},
]

Expected Output
//same targetvalue and no include of `FI or IT` so return
[
 {id:3, name: "lisa", code: "SG", targetvalue: "234"},
  {id:4, name: "ben", code: "SP", targetvalue: "234"},
] 


****

var arrobj3 =[
  {id:1, name: "sonu", code: "IT", targetvalue: "908"},
  {id:3, name: "lisa", code: "FI", targetvalue: "234"},
  {id:4, name: "ben", code: "FI", targetvalue: "234"},
]
Expected Output
// targetvalue and code same
 [ {id:3, name: "lisa", code: "FI", targetvalue: "234"},
  {id:4, name: "ben", code: "FI", targetvalue: "234"}]

I tried

const checkIdList = list => {
    const idlist = ['IN', 'FI'];
    const resultarray = list
      .map((obj, i) => list.find((elem, index) => {
        if (i !== index && elem.targetvalue === obj.targetvalue && 
           (element.code === obj.code || idlist.includes(element.code)) {
          return obj;
        }
      }))
      .filter(x => x);
    return resultarray;
  };
var finalResult = this.checkIdList(arrobj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by grouping the elements by `targetValue` and then filter the `Object.values` of the result by your three conditions:

```js
function checkIdList(array, list) {
  // group by targetValue
  const grouped = {};
  for (const o of array) {
    (grouped[o.targetvalue] ??= []).push(o);
  }

  return Object.values(grouped)
    .filter(g =>
      g.length > 1  // subarrays of length > 1 indicate duplicates
      && (
        g.every(({ code }) => !list.includes(code)) || // if every code is not in the list
        g.every(({ code }, _, a) => code === a[0].code) // OR include if all codes are equal and included in list
      ))
    .flat();
}

const arraylist = ["IT", "FI"];
const arrobj1 = [{ id: 1, name: "sonu", code: "IT", targetvalue: "908" }, { id: 2, name: "abi", code: "IT", targetvalue: "834" }, { id: 3, name: "lisa", code: "SP", targetvalue: "834" }, { id: 4, name: "ben", code: "FI", targetvalue: "234" },];
const arrobj2 = [{ id: 1, name: "sonu", code: "IT", targetvalue: "908" }, { id: 2, name: "abi", code: "IT", targetvalue: "834" }, { id: 3, name: "lisa", code: "SG", targetvalue: "234" }, { id: 4, name: "ben", code: "SP", targetvalue: "234" },];
const arrobj3 = [{ id: 1, name: "sonu", code: "IT", targetvalue: "908" }, { id: 3, name: "lisa", code: "FI", targetvalue: "234" }, { id: 4, name: "ben", code: "FI", targetvalue: "234" },];

console.log(checkIdList(arrobj1, arraylist));
console.log(checkIdList(arrobj2, arraylist));
console.log(checkIdList(arrobj3, arraylist));
```